# API Call Error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.example

Tags: android

dRuntime          com.example.amphibiansapp            E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.amphibiansapp, PID: 15044
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for java.util.List<com.example.amphibiansapp.model.Ambhibian>
for method AmphibiansApiService.getAllAmphibians
at retrofit2.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:54)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.createResponseConverter(HttpServiceMethod.java:126)
at retrofit2.HttpServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(HttpServiceMethod.java:85)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.parseAnnotations(ServiceMethod.java:39)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:202)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:160)
at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
at $Proxy2.getAllAmphibians(Unknown Source)
at com.example.amphibiansapp.ui.AmphibiansViewModel$getAmphibians$1.invokeSuspend(AmphibiansViewModel.kt:33)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
at com.example.amphibiansapp.ui.AmphibiansViewModel.getAmphibians(AmphibiansViewModel.kt:30)
at com.example.amphibiansapp.ui.AmphibiansViewModel.(AmphibiansViewModel.kt:26)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:322)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:304)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:175)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:138)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:156)
at com.example.amphibiansapp.ui.ComposableSingletons$AmphibiansAppKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(AmphibiansApp.kt:43)
at com.example.amphibiansapp.ui.ComposableSingletons$AmphibiansAppKt$lambda-3$1.invoke(AmphibiansApp.kt:24)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:134)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt$Surface$1.invoke(Surface.kt:117)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
at androidx.compose.material.SurfaceKt.Surface-F-jzlyU(Surface.kt:114)
at com.example.amphibiansapp.ui.ComposableSingletons$AmphibiansAppKt$lambda-4$1.invoke(AmphibiansApp.kt:19)
at com.example.amphibiansapp.ui.ComposableSingletons$AmphibiansAppKt$lambda-4$1.invoke(AmphibiansApp.kt:18)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:116)
at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)

try to hit
https://android-kotlin-fun-mars-server.appspot.com/amphibians

Answer (score 0):

Add to your build.gradle file last line to plugins

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization' version '1.8.10'
}
```

After that add internet permission to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```